# How can I update my data using an observable list and an editable table view

Tags: javafx, tableview, observablelist

I've been trying this for quite some time myself and did lots of research. However, I have not come up with a solution.
In my table view, I have an editable column. I can change the data in that table and print it in the controller.

TableView:

```
    <TableColumn fx:id="colQTY" editable="true" onEditCommit="#changeQty" prefWidth="35.0" text="Ist">
        <cellValueFactory>
          <PropertyValueFactory property="sQuantity" />
        </cellValueFactory>
        <cellFactory>
        <TextFieldTableCell fx:factory="forTableColumn" />
        </cellFactory>
    </TableColumn>
```

Controller:

```
    @FXML
    private void changeQty(CellEditEvent<?,?> event) {
        System.out.println(event.getNewValue().toString());
    }
```

The data is in an sqlite database, represented by an observable list

Data Class:

```
public class SupplyData {
    public SimpleStringProperty sPart;
    public SimpleStringProperty sLocation;
    public SimpleStringProperty sQuantity;
    
    public SupplyData(String sPart, String sLocation, String sQuantity) {
        this.sPart= new SimpleStringProperty(sPart);
        this.sLocation= new SimpleStringProperty(sLocation);
        this.sQuantity= new SimpleStringProperty(sQuantity);
    }   
    
    public void setsPart(String sPart) {
        this.sPart.set(sPart);
    }
    
    public String getsPartl() {
        return sPart.get();
    }
    
    public SimpleStringProperty sPartProperty() {
        return sPart;
    }
    
    public void setsLocation(String sLocation) {
        this.sLocation.set(sLocation);
    }
    
    public String getsLocation() {
        return sLocation.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty sLocationProperty() {
        return sLocation;
    }

    public void setsQuantity(String sQuantity) {
        this.sQuantity.set(sQuantity);
    }
    
    public String getsQuantity() {
        return sQuantity.get();
    }
    
    public SimpleStringProperty sQuantityProperty() {
        return sQuantity;
    }
}
```

Data Access Class:

```
public class SupplyDataAccess {

    private ObservableList<SupplyData> supplies;

    public SupplyDataAccess() {
        supplies = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    }

    public ObservableList<SupplyData> getSupplies() {
        return supplies;
    }

    public static Connection connectDB(String sDB) {
        Connection myDB = null;
        try {
            myDB = DriverManager.getConnection(sDB);
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        
        return myDB;
    }    
    
    public void loadData(){

        SupplyData data;
        
        String sDB = "jdbc:sqlite:c:\\supplies.db";
        String sQuery = "select * from supplies;";
        Connection myDB = connectDB(sDB);
        

        try{
        
            ResultSet rs = myDB.createStatement().executeQuery(sQuery);
            while(rs.next()) {
                data = new SupplyData(  rs.getString("Part"),
                                        rs.getString("Location"),
                                        rs.getString("Quantity"));
                supplies.add(data);
            } //while
            rs.close();
            myDB.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }               
                
    }//loadData
    
} //class
```

The controller has this code snipplet to populate the tableview:

```
    public void initialize(){
        
        dataAccess = new SupplyDataAccess();
        dataAccess.loadData();
        tblSupplies.setItems(dataAccess.getSupplies());
    }
```

That works and I can change the quantity. It is visible in the table view. How can I write the new value back to the observable list and from there to the database?

How can I access the other fields in changeQty in the controller? Part and Location are the fields I need to identify the record in the underlying database. If I can access those values in the controller, I can pass them to the data access class and create a SQL statement. That's not a problem.

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Comment: what's the problem, exactly? How is the (newly editied, I assume?) quantity _visible in the tableView_  but you still want _write the new value back to the observable list_? It's the one or other, the tableView typically show's what's in the backing list. Time for a [mcve] :) That said: a) you either let the automagic work or provide a commit handler - with the latter, it's your job to write the edited value back to the item b) don't use propertyValueFactory (astonished that your slightly .. adventurous naming scheme is working at all :), instead expose and use the property

Comment: Hello Kleopatra,

the problem is, I edit the quantity and press enter. In changeQty, I see the new value. If I now call a method in the data access class to show all the entries of the observable list, I still see the old value.I'm quite new to this sort of programming. What do you mean with "adventurous naming scheme" and "expose and use the property"?
How do I do that? If there is a better way, I'm all for it. 
The code is on my laptop at home. I can produce the example only later today.
Thanks,
Michael

Comment: a) work through a tutorial on how to use a commit handler (and make sure you understand the first part of the "a" in my last comment ;) trying again: it's __your__ job to write the editied value to whereever you need it if you install a commit handler, doing so disables the default behavior b) learn about fx naming patterns and compare with yours c) learn about Properties et al (the fx classes)  and api patterns around those .. all handled in basic tutorials (that's what you need to work through when being _quite new to this sort of programming_)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
The commit handler I had created (onEditCommit="#changeQty") didn't do anything but showing the new value. After I deleted the commit handler, the ObservableList was updated as it should.
That brought me back to the problem of how to update the database to make the change persistent.
I created the commit handler again, update the observable list, and call a method in the data access class to update the database. Like so

```
    @FXML
    private void updateQty(CellEditEvent<SupplyData,String> event) {
        //this defines ChangedSupply and writes the current row of the table to it
        SupplyData ChangedSupply = event.getRowValue();
        
        //this updates the observable list
        ChangedSupply.setsQuantity(event.getNewValue());
        
        //this in the end updates the database
        dataAccess.updateData(ChangedSupply);
    }
```

Thanks to @kleopatra for pointing me in the right direction.
Maybe this helps someone else in the future.